# How can I style a disabled button in a Windows 8 JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, css, windows, windows-8

I'm trying to create a Windows 8 app using JavaScript. I'm trying to set the style for a disabled button using CSS, but no matter what I do the button when disabled gets rendered the same.

Does anyone know how to set the style of the disabled button for Windows 8 apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `:disabled` pseudo-class. It works for all the elements.

Comment: Pseudo-elements include `::before` and `::after`. `:disabled` and e.g. `:hover` are pseudo-classes.

Comment: Yeah I already tried the :disabled pseudo-class but unfortunately the app doesnt render the style that i specify

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle reproducing the problem so we can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Uhm, a jsfiddle wouldnt help here as the exact same code is rendered correctly in the web world, but the windows app is the one failing so i ahve a feeling its something to do with setting the disable property in winjs

Comment: Mmm... i didn't know that, no experience with Windows 8 apps here so i can't help you. Hope you solve this soon!

Comment: Solved, apparently you need to give the button and id and then in the css use #id:disabled so that the css then styles the disabled button.

Comment: Did you try input[type="button"]:disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery we can do this

```
$('#ButtonID').attr('disabled',true);
```

By Javascript

```
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=true;
```

By HTML5

```
<button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking.